# How to apply bound to the PIXI text

Tags: canvas, 2d, pixi.js

In PIXI js is is there any way to apply mask on the text. We can use `wordWrapWidth` to limit width of the text.
Is there any way to limit the total height of multiline text?

Intended outcome:

[image]

Comment: Can you show some example (image etc) of the effect that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Put your PIXI.Text object as a child of a PIXI.Container, set a mask on the container that matches the rectangle's dimensions.